# wpf binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using MVVM, I have a View that contains a DependencyProperty, and a ListBox that is bound to the ViewModel:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedServerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedServer",typeof(object),
    typeof(ServerView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(test));


public object SelectedServer
{
    get { return GetValue(SelectedServerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedServerProperty, value); }
}

public ServerView()
{
    SetBinding(SelectedServerProperty, "SelectedServer");
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static void test(DependancyObject sender, DependancyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServer}" />
```

and a ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
ServerModel _selectedServer;
public ServerModel SelectedServer
{
    get { return _selectedServer; }
    set 
    {
        _selectedServer = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedServer");
    }
}
```

When i select an item in the list, the ViewModel is updated, but the DependencyProperty in the View stays the same. even the test event i created is not triggered.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you aware that you are binding an object of type `ServerModel` to an object of type `ServerView` ?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys no.. where?

Comment: look in your DependencyProperty definition, also you misspelled `DependencyProperty` so I wonder how your code compiles

Comment: @thumbmunkeys [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx) the first type is object, the ServerView is the owner.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, what is the link for?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys to show you that the binding is correct.

Comment: @VioletPig why are you binding both view and view model to the ComboBox? also this.SetBinding (in constructor) adds binding to view, not combobox

Comment: @amnezjak It's basically a UserControl that I want to put in a different View. So I need a way to bind the selected item to the main view. I'm binding both the DependencyProperty and the ListBox to the ViewModel.

Comment: If your `DataContext` is set on the `ViewModel`, the `DependencyProperty` in the `View` won't be bound because it isn't in scope. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bob he calls SetBinding in the ctor.

Comment: Show us your ItemsSource "Servers" , additionally call SetBinding after the View is Loaded not in the Ctor . 

can you see any binding errors in your output window or by using snoop ?

Comment: @eran_otzap `ObservableCollection<ServerModel> Servers` nothing special about it..

Comment: @eran_otzap I put the `SetBinding` in the OnLoaded event and it works! Thanks!

Comment: o'k , the reason for this is that the Binding object was created before you ViewModel. 
You should look in your output window or learn how to use snoop , it throws a Binding error is such situations .

Comment: @eran_otzap I checked. there wasn't anything about binding in the output window.

Comment: couldn't you add the .SetBinding after InitializeComponent() as well?

Comment: I think the `SetBinding` is trying to bind to a `Property` defined in the View and not VM. So try using the syntax `SetBinding(SelectedServerProperty, new Binding("SelectedServer"));`. This would try to bind to the `SelectedServer` property in the VM (`DataContext` of the View).[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273(v=vs.110).aspx) is the link from MSDN which would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `SetBinding` is trying to bind to a `Property` defined in the View and not VM. So try using the syntax

```
SetBinding(SelectedServerProperty, new Binding("SelectedServer"));
```

This would try to bind to the `SelectedServer` property in the VM (`DataContext` of the View).[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the link from MSDN which would help you.